# Simulating Human Interface Device via Bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, human-interface

Is there a way to simulate a human interface device (HID) using c# ? What i am trying to do is to connect 2 devices (first one is a pc and will host my application, and second device can be a pc or a mobile device) via Bluetooth. After connecting the devices i will send mouse or keyboard input from my host pc to the other device. First of all, is this possible ? If so how ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes, it can be done. To answer how would be enormous. Why do you need this? Is the exercise to play with and learn how to code for bluetooth or is this just a means to an end? If the latter, perhaps there is an easier and/or better solution.

Comment: hi @J... thanks for the answer. This is some kind of research and development project. I have a hardware. I use some of its functions via a dll which the producer company provides. I have a windows forms application. I can use the hardware as a mouse using the dll. But i want to be able to use it on a tablet pc. But we are not allowed to install anything on the tablets.  So I am trying to manage this by getting the data to my pc from hardware and sending it to the tablet by bluetooth. Please let me know if there is a simpler way. Thanks.

Comment: There is a simpler way, no doubt, but would certanly involve installing software on the "forbidden" tablet.  Writing a bluetooth driver won't be easy, however.  You'll probably want to start with http://32feet.net/content/32feet.aspx and http://www.bluetooth.com/Pages/Tech-Info.aspx

Comment: Cant I make it work if i first connect the tablet to my pc and send information via bluetooth according to bluetooth mouse profile specs?

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way and this is far too broad a problem to solve in a simple answer on SO.

Comment: In fact, 32feet won't even work - HID operates over L2CAP and isn't exposed by libraries like 32feet.  The only way to do this is a very low level ground-up driver.  If you could install software on the tablet it would be very much easier.