# C# emulate HID clicker bluetooth

Tags: c#

I need some guidance on how or whether this is possible to achieve without a "server" application running on the pc.
I have gotten as far as establishing a bluetooth connection to the PC, I would like to send HID commands to control a slideshow similar to how a clicker works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling PowerPoint Slideshow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994892/controlling-powerpoint-slideshow)

Comment: @AndersTornblad Not a duplicate, completely irrelevant question. I have a sepcific question about HID.

Comment: Ah, then you shouldn't put the very specific word PowerPoint in the title OR the content text!

Comment: I mean the question is about powerpoint and hid...

Comment: Then you have two separate questions. Or you should rethink what your goal is. If you want to write software in C# for controlling a PowerPoint presentation, the link I provided will help you do exactly that, but without simulating a HID device, which is not necessary for controlling a PowerPoint presentation. If you want to simulate HID input in general, it has nothing to do with PowerPoint.

Comment: @AndersTornblad The topic you posted Is for controlling powerpoint from an application running locally. I am looking for a way to send HID commands similar to a cordless presenter via bluetooth. See https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/HID.aspx
Also wondering whether this is even possible.

Comment: Would any of this be similar to what you are looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916569.aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632614/what-events-are-fired-by-bluetooth-avrcp-commands-in-windows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160402/simulating-human-interface-device-via-bluetooth

Comment: @StevenByrne [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160402/simulating-human-interface-device-via-bluetooth) is not, because he states he is running a server on his machine to interpret commands. Picture this scenario, you buy a clicker at Best Buy, and you connect it via bluetooth to your PC. You launch your favorite SlideShow program and start switching slides with your new clicker. You never installed any server software or anything, the clicker is simply plug and play because it adheres to HID. I want to do this with software.

Comment: Granted I'm no expert on the subject but it installs software and drivers. My understanding would be the USB receives the Bluetooth clicks, then runs HID commands, the USB being the server, the controller being the client. I could be totally off on this, but I thought that's how it worked?

Comment: @StevenByrne As far as AVRCP, that is just another [bluetooth profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Human_Interface_Device_Profile_.28HID.29) just like HID but less apt for this particular situation.

Comment: @StevenByrne No server is installed. I believe HID is a specification/profile where you send commands specifically formatted in a way where an HID-compatible receiver is able to interpret them and notify the device to act in a certain way. I could be wrong on the specifics.

Comment: You're probably right, my thought though being that the USB has firmware on it that receives information; I thought this was how they paired them with the controller; which if they had to do that any ways I would think they would just have the remote send a Bluetooth command to the USB that converts it into HUD commands on the local machine. Otherwise it would have to redundantly check every command to see what device was sending it, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131852/discussion-between-francisco-aguilera-and-steven-byrne).

Comment: Your responses to comments seem to indicate the question, as asked, is not what you want to ask.  Here is my current interpretation, based on what you've said in comments and the chat: you want to provide an actual bluetooth device that provides HID commands over bluetooth that control powerpoint.  I'm not currently sure where "C#" "emulate" come in to that?  Are you trying to write the bluetooth device's firmware in C#?  If so, using what platform, Netduino or something?  I would honestly vote to close this as-is, but I can't because you put a bounty on it.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @AlexLyman See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PDF outlined by [this link](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=245141) is an excellent, detailed, platform-agnostic resource on sending HID commands via a Bluetooth connection. It talks about having your device set up as a server, and what the relevant commands to send over the link.
So, to answer #1 - it is possible.
2 [this document](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=245141) outlines how it is done.

Answer (score 1):

while it is possible, as far as I know, under windows that would involve either

- using an external bluetooth HID module (like this http://www.instructables.com/id/3-Bluetooth-HID-Module-HC05-With-RN42-Firmware/)
- writing a semi custom bluetooth driver to appear as a HID device.

if you have an external HID module, it's easy, just talk to it via rs232 (serial), and it will send whatever you want, though you will need to buy some hardware.

it seems like you can get away with just patching the windows bluetooth driver instead of writing one. https://nadavrub.wordpress.com/2015/07/17/simulate-hid-device-with-windows-desktop/

If you have access to linux instead, using a already available library for that would probably be the safest and easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548(v=vs.110).aspx

to simulate mouse events with the same effect as a powerpoint click and as for the bluetooth, I'm not sure.